# How to invalid HttpSession in Vaadin

Tags: httpsession, vaadin7

Atm, my project using Vaadin 7. And i'm creating a login form. I need to invalid session before log in user so user will get new session id each time.

Currently, i try to get VaadinSession, then get WrappedSession, and finally invalid that WrappedSession.

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().invalidate();
```

This did invalidate my HttpSession and generate new session id ( Which calling close() from VaadinSession can't do it ). But after i invalidate my session, UI hang without any error.

So is it correct to invalid HttpSession this way? Or there some better way to invalid session ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after a while checking class reference, this is the correct way to handle it in Vaadin 7:

```
VaadinService.reinitializeSession(VaadinService.getCurrentRequest());
```

They changed class which hold this method, making me have a hard time finding it.